# A Micropyhton abstract robot library for pi-pico based robot kits

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, robotics

I'm looking for a slightly higher level Micropyhon library for pi-pico based robot kits. There seem to be many simple robot kits with similar hardware on the market at reasonable prices, but the software that comes with it tend to piece-meal demos of how to use a small featureset at a time with no overall guide to how to integrate things.  E.g. a BT "remote control" example or an object avoidance example. There is very little guide to how to integrate the features to create a more full featured robot. Generally the code is poorly factored making it hard to combine functionality.

Is there a higher level robot library for Micropython that abstracts somewhat over the hardware and comes with good examples of how to integrate features? It would be great if it has a sensible main-loop that allows different hardware functionalities to be integrated without having to do a large amount of refactoring first. I've done a significant amount of google searching (e.g. ["abstract microphython robotics library"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=abstract+microphython+robotics+library) and have not been able to find anything fitting the bill.

As an example, I recently got a [Waveshare Pico Go](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/PicoGo) that seems to have a reasonably standard assortment of hardware modules (differential drive wheels, ultrasonic sensors, various IR sensors, a BT module, display, some neopixel leds, etc) for a family member. While it comes with some examples of how to use the hardware features they are all coded very ad-hoc in a way that makes it very hard for an inexperienced coder to combine them. It looks like [another questioner on this stack](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/143434/mecanum-robot-for-pico) also ran into similar issues.

Comment: Maybe try https://robotics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah yes, "***abstraction***" is the key idea; another is "***system integration***". At a even lower level, "***mircopython***" for Rpi pico and ESP, ...